# How to produce RDD[Result] for unit testing

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

for unit testing purpose I am building my own HBase Result object as follows

```
val row = Bytes.toBytes( "row01" )
val cf = Bytes.toBytes( "cf" )
val cell1 = new KeyValue( row, cf, "v1".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes( "file1" ) )
val cell2 = new KeyValue( row2, cf, "v2".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes( "file2" ) )

val cells = List( cell1, cell2 )

val result = Result.create( cells )
```

Now I want to add this to a sparkContext Object , like

```
val sparkContext = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext( conf )
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize( List( result ) )
```

However, once I try to access the rdd via foreach , like

```
rdd.foreach{x=>x}
```

I get the famous Spark Task Not serializable.

Does anyone know of a better way to crete RDD[Result]?

Answer (score 1):

`Result` is not serializable, so if you want an `RDD[Result]` you have to produce the `Result`s on the node itself from some other input (and of course, then actions like `collect`, `first` which would send `Result`s between nodes etc. won't work). So e.g.

```
val rdd0 = sparkContext.parallelize( List( ("row", "cf") ) )

val rdd = rdd.map { case (str1, str2) =>
  val row = Bytes.toBytes( str1 )
  val cf = Bytes.toBytes( str2 )
  val cell1 = new KeyValue( row, cf, "v1".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes( "file1" ) )
  val cell2 = new KeyValue( row2, cf, "v2".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes( "file2" ) )

  val cells = List( cell1, cell2 )

  Result.create( cells )
}
```